# Swift in Playground Producing Division Error

Tags: swift, math, swift-playground

```
var a = 127.0
var b = 5.0
a / b

var c:Float
c = 127
var d:Float
d = 5
c/d
```

In Playground, a/b returns 25.4, but c/d returns 25.39999961…

Why?

Is this result going to be the same when the code is compiled and run?

Is there something I'm failing to do to get correct arithmetic answers in Swift?

Thanks,

MB

Answer (score 1):

This is because `a` and `b` are both `doubles`, so they have twice the floating point precision compared to `floats`.